# python import from gdbinit doesn't work

Tags: python, opencv, gdb, gdbinit

I have installed python-opencv and I can run `import cv2` and check version without problems from a python shell.

When trying to source [this python file](https://github.com/crep4ever/matrix-viewer/blob/master/misc/matrix-viewer-gdb.py) in gdb to provide a new gdb command I always get:

```
(gdb) source /opt/src/matrix-viewer/misc/matrix-viewer-gdb.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/src/matrix-viewer/misc/matrix-viewer-gdb.py", line 17, in <module>
    import cv2.cv as cv
ImportError: No module named 'cv2'
```

My PC has got the sole python instance from Ubuntu distribution, why from gdb I'm getting an import problem regarding this just installed package that I'm able to load from a python shell.

---

### EDIT

This is a python 2 package, and gdb loads python 3... Seems unsolvable.

Comment: Could be that path variables are not correctly set/read from gdb?

Comment: Build gdb from source against python 2 (--with-python) if that's what you need...

Comment: @ssnobody I realize that's an option but I'm not so into this, nevermind, this case is not worth it.

Comment: also, please stop using the deprecated cv2.cv. it will be gone tomorrow.

Comment: @berak go tell it to the authors of the projects I'm using please. I'd be glad.